# Externally excited induction generator

Tags: induction-motor

I read a statement in my textbook-" The short circuit current of the externally-excited 3phase induction generator is limited" which I am unable to understand. Kindly help

Comment: Some more context is required. How is an induction generator excited if not externally?

Comment: The other way by using a capacitor bank which would supply for both the induction generator and load. By Externally excited I mean the induction generator is directly connected to AC supply system.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know what point the quoted sentence is intending to make without knowing something about the overall context in the chapter. If a short circuit occurs as a fault, the induction generator would initially contribute to the fault current, but the excitation would collapse due to the fault. That would limit the fault current contribution of an induction generator in comparison to a permanent-magnet generator or a wound-field synchronous generator with and excitation system that would have some energy storage. The effect of any capacitors that might contribute to the induction motor excitation would quickly diminish also.

A doubly fed induction generator would probably have energy stored in the rotor converter, but the converter would still shut down rather quickly in the event of a short circuit.

A fault can never appear as a short circuit everywhere in the network. All of the seemingly negligible impedances between one place in the distribution system and another are much more significant at the occurrence of a short circuit. In order to determine the short-circuit current at any point, it is necessary to simulate the network including every component.

Answer (score 0):

The Electrical Machine has resistance in the stator windings .Also there is inductance. The output voltage is finite               .The term" Synchronous  Impedance  " covers this .

Answer (score 0):

An ideal generator is current limited by the strength of the magnetic field in the rotor, the the short-circuit current it that which exactly cancels the rotor's magnetic field. In real life it is further reduced by non-idealities like winding resistance and the imperfect magnetic coupling between the rotor and the stator etc...